# Powershell select mouseover link then item on drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, powershell

I'm trying to automate some routine tasks for checking a webapp after an upgrade. I can launch the browser, navigate to the website and logon to the webapp. But from there it gets a little more difficult, the site uses javascript for the menus. The main menus are activated by mouseover and then the sub menu can be clicked on.

Is there a way to do an equivalent to a mouseover and then click on the sub menu option. Here's some of what I've tried so far. (But doesn't work)

```
$links = ($ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('log off')) | where {$_.InnerText -eq 'Exit'}
   $links.click()
```

Any help would be appreciated on this, make a nice end to the week. :-)

Comment: I doubt you have an element with the tag name `log off` (you can't have a space in the tag name). The tag name is most likely `a`, `div`, `li` or similar, and might not be a good query to find your element. Without knowledge of your DOM I can't say which query you should use, but if the element has an ID you could do `$ie.Document.getElementById('myElementId')`. On the other hand, the follow up question is if automating IE using PowerShell is the right tool for testing a web site. While it should work, perhaps you should look into using Selenium or the Visual Studio test tools?

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about selenium, I'll try using that once I've learned it. :-)